# Read multiple data by Bluetooth Serial with Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, bluetooth, arduino, ionic3

I've a very simple application, I need to send measurement data via Bluetooth from my Arduino to my Ionic application (Android).

But I have questions about the correct way to do this on Ionic.

Arduino Code

```
char BTString;

/* serial1 is a BluetoothSerial instance */
if (serial1.available()) {
    BTString = serial1.read();

    /* S is the command that my Ionic application sends to start the measurement */
    if (BTString == 'S') {
            BTString = "";

        /* Here is where I will do the calculations of the measurements and send the results via Bluetooth, but in this example I will only send hypothetical results */

            serial1.write("D"); // This indicates Start
            serial1.write("45.55"); // measurement 1
            serial1.write("79.80"); // measurement 2
            serial1.write("67.20"); // measurement 3
            serial1.write("F"); // This indicates the end
    }
}
```

Ionic Code

```
  this._bluetoothSerial.write('S') // Start the measurement
  .then((data: any) => {
    this.measuring(); // Wait for results
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    this.errorCommBluetooth(); // Error alert
  });


  private measuring(): void {
    this.readOk = false;

    do {
      this._bluetoothSerial.available()
      .then((data: any) => {
        this._bluetoothSerial.readUntil('F')
        .then((data: any) => {

          if (data[0] == 'D') {
            this.measurement1 = data[1] + data[2] + data[3] + data[4] + data[5];
            this.measurement2 =  data[6] + data[7] + data[8] + data[9] + data[10];
            this.measurement3 =  data[11] + data[12] + data[13] + data[14] + data[15];

            this.readOk = true;
          }

        });
      });
    }while (this.readOk == false);
  }
```

This code does not work.

Please, what would be the best way to do this and store the measurements in the 3 variables, using the readUntil function or not.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! This code worked for me:

```
this._bluetoothSerial.available()
.then((number: any) => {
    this._bluetoothSerial.read()
    .then((data: any) => {
      if (data[0] == "D" && data[16] == "F") {
        this.measure1 = parseFloat(data[1]+data[2]+data[3]+data[4]+data[5]);
        this.measure2 = parseFloat(data[6]+data[7]+data[8]+data[9]+data[10]);
        this.measure3 = parseFloat(data[11]+data[12]+data[13]+data[14]+data[15]);

        this._bluetoothSerial.clear();
      }
    });
});
```